# Python 3.x Reading files with headers (data between identified headers)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, text, abaqus

I'm using Python 3.4, and I have NunPy/SciPy already installed.
I need to read a text file with the following structure:

```
*Node
  1, -0.600000024,   1.20000005,           0.
  2, -0.600000024,  0.300000012,           0.
  3, -0.480560571,    0.1741862,           0.
  4, -0.335430175, 0.0791868418,           0.
  (...)
  n, x, y, z
*Element
  1, 1, 2, 3, 4
  2, 5, 6, 7, 8
  (...)
  n, a, b, c, d
```

From this txt file I need to create a matrix called "node", which contains the info between *Node and *Element, I mean, it has to have 4 columns and n lines, for example:

node=array([1, -0.600000024, 1.20000005, 0.],[2, -0.600000024, 0.300000012,           0.], [3, -0.480560571, 0.1741862, 0.],[4, -0.335430175, 0.0791868418,           0.], [n, x, y, z])

And another matrix called "element", which contains the lines after *Element:

element=array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 5, 6, 7, 8], [n, a, b, c, d])

Indeed, I need just to "read" the text file and write this content into two matrices. However, I have to separete the information that is under *Node from that under *Element. I have to have two matrices, one with nodes and other with elements... But I'm new at Python and have no idea on how to read a text file in this way and generate those matrices...

I'd appreciate any help/example. Thanks a lot!

Comment: is that the entire file? (nothing before or after the node/element data?)  Typically there are more keywords in an abaqus input file, but of course it simplifies things if thats all there is.

Comment: Yes that is the whole file...
I mean, I have to program my own finite element solver (2D) for a course at University. And since I'm an Abaqus user, I will read nodes and elements in Abaqus format, just because doing this, I can prepare the model in an easier way (using some pre-processor). 
I was in doubt if I should use Python or Matlab/Octave. I have only very basic knowledge on both, so I'll have to study anyway and then I've chosen Python. 
Was it the better choice? =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a list with the lines in your file, then creating sub lists starting and stopping at the `index` if `'*Node'` and `'*Element'` should work for you:

```
r=[]
s = open('File.txt')
For line in s:
  r.append(line.strip('\n'))
Node=[]
Element=[]
For i in r[r.index('*Node')+1:r.index('*Element')]:
  Node.append(map(float,i.split(',')))
For j in r[r.index('*Element')+1:]:
  Element.append(map(int, j.split(','))
Node=np.array(Node)
Element=np.array(Element)
```

Comment: Hi EoinS, Thanks for this answer.
I didn't understand the usage of:
Node.append(map(float,i.split(',')))

Why not using only: Node.append(i.split(','))

If I use the "map", how do I retrieve the values to opperate on them?
Thanks!

Obs.: I'm sorry, I'm just starting with Python...

Comment: @Paulo With map, the first argument is a function, so you can operate on the values by defining a function that processes one value and passing it in as the first parameter. Here `float` is used to cast the strings given by split into floating point numbers, instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

[@EoinS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37505854/1594060) has an excellent solution, I wanted to present an alternative that is less dynamic in terms of figuring out where the two lists type begin and end but will handle the various edge cases in CSV formatting and has column names is the following:

```
import numpy as np

node_rows = 75 #number of lines in the node section
interstitial_rows = 5 #number of lines between the last node record and the first element
element_rows = 1000 #the number of element rows

nodes = np.genfromtxt(
    'sample.csv',           # file name
    skip_header=1,          # lines to skip at the top, i assume there is a header
    skip_footer=(interstitial_rows + 1 + element_rows),          # lines to skip at the bottom, add one for the column name row at the end
    delimiter=',',          # column delimiter
    names=['n', 'x', 'y', 'z'])

elements = np.genfromtxt(
    'sample.csv',           # file name
    skip_header=(1 + node_rows + interstitial_rows),          # lines to skip at the top, i assume there is a header
    skip_footer=(1),          # one for the column name row at the end
    delimiter=',',          # column delimiter
    names=['n', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

Note that I haven't tested this code, I use similar code all the time but there may be a syntax error or something I missed.

You can find more about how to read CSVs with numpy [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) and [here](https://www.getdatajoy.com/examples/python-data-analysis/read---write-csv-file-with-numpy)

Comment: Thanks Josh! I'll try that!